# Как подключить дамп данных MySQL

Tags: mysql, python, база-данных, django, debian

Опыта использовании MySQL - нет.

Ситуация такая: имеется проект на Django (ОС: Debian), но для его работоспособности необходимо создать таблицы. Если использовать `python manage.py syncdb` (используется `south`), то в результате происходит конфликт таблиц. В качестве варианта решения данной проблемы мне передали дамп базы данных. Но у меня не получается им воспользоваться.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне воспользоваться принятым дампом БД (`damp.sql.zip`) и тем самым решить конфликт с таблицами?

Comment: Выполнить переданный вам sql-код в базе sqlite3, очевидно

Comment: @andreymal как это сделать?

Comment: `cat damp.sql | sqlite3 /path/to/new_sqlite_file.db`?

Comment: @MaxU в результате: `   ...>` - это нормально? А файл `new_sqlite_file.db` не изменил размер (0кб)

Comment: @EmptyMan, проверьте есть ли `COMMIT;` в конце DUMP файла...

Comment: @MaxU это последняя строка `/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;`

Comment: Это очень похоже на MySQL dump - вы уверены, что это SQLite dump???

Comment: @MaxU не уверен. Установлю MySQL и проверю. Спасибо!